# Django query: Get states sorted by employee count

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I want to run the following SQL query using the Django ORM. I don't want to use raw sql because I want to concatenate it with another query.

```
SELECT count(e.id), o.state
FROM core_employeemodel e, core_officemodel o
WHERE e.office_id = o.id
GROUP BY o.state 
ORDER BY -count(e.id);
```

Models:

```
class OfficeModel(Model):
    address1 = CharField('address 1', max_length=50,)
    address2 = CharField('address 2', max_length=50, blank=True)
    city = CharField('city', max_length=50, db_index=True)
    state = CharField('state', max_length=2, choices=STATE_CHOICES, db_index=True)
    zip_code = CharField('zip code', max_length=50, db_index=True)
    phone = CharField('phone', max_length=50,)
    fax = CharField('fax', max_length=50, blank=True)

class EmployeeModel(Model):
    first_name = CharField('first name', max_length=50, db_index=True)
    last_name = CharField('last name', max_length=50, db_index=True)
    picture = ImageField('picture', upload_to='employee_picture/', blank=True,)
    fax = CharField('fax', max_length=50, blank=True)
    email = EmailField('email', unique=True)
```

I tried with annotations but I did not get a good result. Can you guys help me out?

Comment: Not without knowing your models...

Comment: There, I added the models!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it:

```
OfficeModel.objects.values('state').annotate(employee_cnt=Count('employee_office')).order_by('-employee_cnt')
```

Hope it helps others!